# To sort files case-sensitively

Tags: macos, finder

Is it possible to sort files case-sensitively, that is, the order should be as follows:

```
README (or, for example, ReadMe)
aaa
zzz
```

instead of (this is how it works for me currently):

```
aaa
README
zzz
```

The question is about contemporary versions of macOS, for instance, Ventura.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get what you’re looking for, use `sort -n` which will evaluate it according to it’s arithmetic value.

```
ls | sort -n
README
abc
zzz
```

From the `sort` man page ([`man sort`](https://ss64.com/osx/sort.html))

> -n     Compare according to arithmetic value an initial numeric string consisting of optional white space, an optional - sign, and zero or more digits, optionally followed by a decimal point and  zero or more digits.

Comment: It seems there is no such setting in Finder?

Comment: Hmmm: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6514334